# Find out points earned from asking questions, answers and editing posts on StackOverflow

Tags: support, reputation

Say I have earned 1000 points on StackOverflow, how can I find out how many of them were from asking questions, giving answers, editing posts, etc.

Comment: Well, in the general case it's rather complex due to the rep cap.  If you have 15 upvotes on answers and 15 upvotes on questions in the same day, trying to determine which ones were below and which above the rep cap isn't easy with the reports given.

Comment: You can go to www.stackoverflow.com/reputation and fetch all the data from there. Each kind of action (asking, answering, accepting) has a different code.

Comment: @fedorqui: Is there an easier way to view this information?

Comment: Mmmm not that I know, @Naveen. You could maybe create a little script to fetch this data and display it in a nicer format.